# How to add org.apache.poi to Karafa

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-karaf

how to add a dependency in the project? OSGI+POI
At execution time this code

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(originalStream);
```

After execute this code, throws error

```
Method threw 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' exception.
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory not found by wrap_mvn_org.apache.poi_poi_3.11 [761]
```

My pom.xml add dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
     <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
     <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>

            <plugin> 
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                   <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                 </instructions>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Install bandle karaf:

```
bundle:install wrap:mvn:org.apache.poi/poi/3.11
bundle:install wrap:mvn:org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.11
bundle:install wrap:mvn:org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.11
bundle:install wrap:mvn:org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1
```

All bundles in Karaf successful install and run

Comment: Attention 
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory not found by wrap_mvn_org.apache.poi_poi_3.11 [761]
Search is not bundle

Comment: Maybe you should use the osgi bundle of poi provided by servicemix (org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi/3.14_1)

Comment: Why are you depending on an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to the newest one?

Comment: updated to the version 3.14 I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexandre Cartapanis you were right

> > > Maybe you should use the osgi bundle of poi provided by servicemix (org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles‌​.poi/3.14_1)

Thanks to all.